# Symmetrical hexiamond figure problem

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

Objective is to make as much symmetrical figures as plausible using one of each L (red/pink), E(green/lime), H(blue) hexiomond. You can rotate, translate, flip them as you please.

My work so far.. 2 figures with their "flipped" counterparts.

Any obvious ones I am missing? I am not trying to prove how many are there just finding as much as plausible.

[image]

Comment: What are you counting as symmetrical? (E.g., all your examples have mirror symmetry but some of McFry's have rotational but not mirror symmetry.)

Answer (score 11):

Here's six more solutions I found:
[image: Imgur]